# local variable 'form' referenced before assignment in python

Tags: python, django

this code always show me error local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

```
def home(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None) 

    if form.is_valid(): 
        form.save() 
        all_items = list.object.all 
        messages.success(request ,('Item Has Been Added To List !')) 
        return render(request ,'home.html', {'all_items': all_items}) 
    else : 
        all_items = list.object.all 
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'all_items': all_items})
```

Comment: why dont you paste the code in your question?

Comment: post your code here instead of links

Comment: Please don't post your code as image.

Comment: What will `form` be if `request.method` is `'GET'`?

Comment: i want to add items so it will be post not get

Comment: Please read up on how to ask questions. Post your code in your original post instead of an image, and not in the comment section without indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The variable *form* is defined only if the the condition `request.method == 'POST'` fulfills otherwise you won't have the *from* variable in the function scope. The code should look like this in order to resolve your issue:

```
if request.method=='POST':
   form = ListForm(request.POST)
else:
   form = ListForm(None)
```

Comment: i don't get your thoughts

Comment: The 'from' variable is defined only if the request.method == 'POST' otherwise you won't have the from variable in the function scope.
The code should look like this in order to resolve your issue:

if request.method=='POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST)
else:
        form = ListForm(None)

Answer (score 0):

```
def home(request):
    all_items = list.object.all()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() 
            messages.success(request ,('Item Has Been Added To List !')) 
            return redirect('home.html') 
    else :
        form = ListForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'all_items': all_items, 'form': form})
```

in case of a get request the form again will be thrown to the user

Comment: i tried this but it came this time with AttributeError

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as the statement will circuit-break on the left side of the `and`

```
if 'form' in locals() and form.is_valid(): 
    ... do something
```

Comment: did you do `if 'form' in locals()` or `if form in locals()` ?

Comment: if 'form' in locals()

Comment: That's odd. Anyway I would just define it as `form = None` after the def.  then do a `if form and form.is_valid():`  that should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ListForm(request.POST or None)
      form = ListForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            all_items = list.objects.all
            messages.success(request, ('Item has been added to do list!'))
            return render(request, "home.html", {'all_itmes':all_items})
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return HttpResponse(form.errors)
    else:
        all_items = list.objects.all
        return render(request, "home.html", {'all_itmes':all_items})
```

Comment: i tried this answer and it worked nested else and if